# error sliceShiftLeft() function

Tags: c, arrays, sorting

```
#include <stdio.h>

void sliceShiftLeft(int array[], int start, int end) {
    if ( start < end ) {
        int temp = array[end];

        for ( int i = start + 1; i < end; i++ ) {
            array[i] = array[i+1];
        }
    array[start] = temp;
    }

}

int main() {
    int start = 2;
    int end = 5;

    int size = 10;
    int array[size];

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        array[i] = i;
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    printf("-------------------------\n");

    sliceShiftLeft(array, start, end);

    for ( int i = 0; i < size; i++ ) {
        printf("%d ", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");

    return 0;
}
```

problem is cycle in sliceShiftLeft() function.

i need 01 2345 6789 to be transformed to 01 5234 6789, but i keep getting 01 5455 6789.

my steps:

1) i put the last number in slice to the temp
2) i run cycle for which puts i+1 to i
3) i put the last number, which is in temp, to the first place.

where's my mistake?

Comment: for ( int i = end; i > start; i-- ) {
            array[i] = array[i-1];
        }
    array[start] = temp;

Comment: so i was just going the wrong direction. the way you showed it works just fine. thanx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the desired output is the one you mentioned in your question then you are going the wrong way, you should:

- store the last element in temp
- move all element from start up to end - 1 to the right
- store last element into start

While you are going exactly the opposite way, with the exception of third step. What happens is:

```
0123456789
0134556789 <- array[i] = array[i+1]
0154556789 <- array[start] = temp
```

Comment: now i see. as i wrote above, my mistake was that i went the wrong direction of array.

Answer (score 0):

your first error is here `for(int i ... )` in the fist part of `for` you mustn't declare a variable but initialize one

Comment: i thought it was acceptable to declare int in the cycle header.